# Use Like function together with CDate function

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2016

I am writing a sql query that searches the date data type. I want to use the Like function with the CDate function, but I get a mismatch error in the data type.

Here is my code;

```
"SELECT * FROM Kasa_Tahsilat WHERE Tarih LIKE CDate('%" & DateTimePicker1.Value & "%') ORDER BY Kimlik DESC"
```

**Note: I'm using VB.NET**

Comment: Whats the value in DateTimePicker1.Value ?

Comment: A DateTimePicker.Value is a DateTime . CDate is not necessary. Thin about it. What could Like possibly mean in reference to a date? The same year? Same day? Same month?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that. *Like* is for strings, not date values, and *octothorpes* must be used as the delimiter:

```
"SELECT * FROM Kasa_Tahsilat WHERE Tarih = #" & DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd") & "# ORDER BY Kimlik DESC"
```

For matching an *interval* of, say, three days:

```
"SELECT * FROM Kasa_Tahsilat WHERE Tarih Between #" & DateTimePicker1.Value.AddDays(-3).ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd") & "# And #" & DateTimePicker1.Value.AddDays(3).ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd") & "# ORDER BY Kimlik DESC"
```